# Dummy starting page in designing an angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, node.js

As my App frontend would be in angular. Below is a flow I have considered for the webapp.

1. User types in the browser `http://www.example.com`
2. Server serves a dummy page with no HTML with the only javascript in angular
3. Now in the code client makes an ajax http get request to may be `http://www.example.com/start`
4. Now if the user is logged in server sends a JSON response with the user info
   for angular to route into the users homepage. Otherwise, an appropriate response is sent and angular routes into the sites normal homepage with options to log in.

As I am new in angular , I was asking is this a good design and if not how do experts do it? 
My problem is not the authentication , my problem is , when I serve static page I have to pass the user info to the client somehow. When client types it in a browser url bar , I don't have any way to capture the response in a javascript code. That's why I have to send a dummy page first so that I can capture create an ajax request to capture the responses in javascript and act accodringly

And also in the angular $http.get does angular automatically sends the previous session info(cookies) or I have to explicitly send it ?

I am using express,nodejs as server in my backend.

Comment: create the index.html initialize the angular js app, in the angular router (angular.config) for the app, set the default route to be the home of the app, for example with `$routeProvider` use the `.otherwise` functionality

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to do user authentication in angular. Question itself is far too broad

Comment: Editing my problem , I don't have problem with authentication, but routing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Server serves a dummy page with no HTML with the only javascript in angular

You should really read a little bit about AngularJS before you start trying to build out a frontend implementation with it - most specific single-page application design.

This is a [great tutorial for building a single page app with AngularJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating).

Essentially, you'll **need** to render some HTML just to load the Angular application and controller(s) required to validate a user's logged in status.

Borrowing some principles from mobile-first design, if you design your interfaces to first look great *without* data - you'll have a decent experience between #3 and #4 while your AngularJS controller decides whether to redirect the user or adjust $scope to affect the UI in some way based on your business logic.

You can use a ton of different treatments for #3 to communicate to the user the status of the application (in terms of verifying their login, re-routing them to some secure area, or declining their access)

Comment: So , instead of sending a blank page , I would send the initial layout and the change the contents after subsequent requests?

Comment: Exactly, in AngularJS since it's all client-side javascript your frontend template mark-up also serves as the scaffolding of your application governing AngularJS closures, DI, which controllers & bootstrapping code runs, etc -- so you need to send at least the skeleton of your application to the user's browser and load "the Angular app" to kick start everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to do this, but I would recommend against it.  Depending on  your user base, there are still enough places in the world and devices with network latency and poor rendering capability, so I would not recommend a completely 'empty' page load w/o javascript.  At a minimum, have some static welcome text or something that gets replaced when  your angular app is done loading.

The cookies should get passed if you [configure it correctly](http://blog.ionic.io/angularjs-authentication/), but I tend to use token-based auth for single page apps.